# A characterization of an Euclidean motion

Tags: geometry, affine-geometry

I have one definition and one proposition, from which I formulated a characterization of Euclidean motion. These are:

> **Definition**: A map $T: \mathbb{E}^n \to \mathbb{E}^n$ is an *affine transformation* if it is given in a coordinate system by $T(\mathbf{x})=A\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{b}$, where $A=(a_{ij})$ is an $n \times n$ matrix with nonzero determinant and $\mathbf{b}=(b_i)$ a vector; in more detail, $$
> \mathbf{x} = (x_i) \mapsto \mathbf{y} = \left( \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_j+b_i \right) \text{,} \quad \text{ or } \quad
> \left( \begin{matrix} x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{matrix} \right) \mapsto A \left( \begin{matrix} x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{matrix} \right) + \left( \begin{matrix} b_1 \\ \vdots \\ b_n \end{matrix} \right) \text{.} \tag{9}
> $$
> ([original picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6jUW.png))

> **Proposition :** Let $f$ be an affine transformation from $R^n$ to $R^n$ given by $f(x)=Ax+b$. Then $f$ is a Euclidean motion if and only if $A^TA=I$.

We also know that every Euclidean motion is an affine transformation. Does it follow that every Euclidean motion $f$ can be associated with the equation  $f(x)=Ax+b$ for some $A$ and $b$, **where $A$ admits $A^TA=I$**?

Assuming that my intuition is correct, I used this fact(?) and the following Lemma in proving the following proposition (which states that Euclidean motions send Euclidean frames to Euclidean frames, whose definition is included below), is it correct?

> **Definition :** An $\mathbf{Euclidean \; frame}$ of $R^n$ is a set of
> $n+1$ points $Q_0,Q_1,...,Q_n$ such that
>
> - $d(Q_0,Q_i)=1 \; \forall i=1,...,n$
> - $(Q_i-Q_0)\cdot(Q_j-Q_0)=0 \; \forall i\not=j$, where "$\cdot$" denotes the dot product on $R^n$.

> **Lemma :** Let $T:R^n \to {R^n}$ be a linear operator on $R^n$ and assume
> that $A$ represents $T$ in the standard basis for $R^n$. Then the
> followings are equivalent:
>
> - $T$ preserves the dot product on $R^n$.
> - $A^TA=I$.

> **Proposition :** Let $f:R^n \to R^n$ be a Euclidean motion. Let {$Q_0,Q_1,...,Q_n$} be a Euclidean frame of $R^n$. Then {$f(Q_0),f(Q_1),...,f(Q_n)$} is a Euclidean frame.
>
> **proof :** Since f is a motion, f preserves distances. Thus, $\forall i=1,...,n$ we have  $d(f(Q_0),f(Q_i))=d(Q_0,Q_i)=1$.
> Since f is a motion, it is also an affine transformation, so $\forall x\in{R^n} f(x)=Ax+b$, where $A\in{M_{nxn}(R)}$ is such that $A^TA=I$, and $b\in{M_{nx1}(R)}$.
> Define $T:R^n \to {R^n}$ by $T(x)=Ax$, i.e, T is represented by $A$ in the standard basis for $R^n$. Then for $i\not=j$, we have
> $(f(Q_i)-f(Q_0))\cdot(f(Q_j)-f(Q_0))=((AQ_i+b)-(AQ_0+b))\cdot((AQ_j+b)-(AQ_0+b))=(A(Q_i-Q_0))\cdot(A(Q_j-Q_0))=(T(Q_i-Q_0))\cdot(T(Q_j-Q_0))$.
> Since $A$ is the representing matrix for $T$ in the standard basis and $A^TA=I$, by the preceding Lemma, $T$ preserves the dot product, so finally we have
> $(T(Q_i-Q_0))\cdot(T(Q_j-Q_0))=(Q_i-Q_0)\cdot(Q_j-Q_0)=0$.

Comment: Regarding your question "Does it follow...": the answer is yes, it is an **immediate** logical consequence of the preceding definition, the preceding proposition, and the stated knowledge that every Euclidean motion is an affine transformation. Because of this immediacy, though, I worry that I am misunderstanding your question. Did you mean to ask something a bit more subtle?

Comment: Regarding your followup question "...is it correct?", please take a look at our guidelines for [formatting and writing your question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10992), with an emphasis on the following part: "The key parts of your question should not be in an embedded image such as a photo/screenshot/etc., such images are not searchable, they are not accessible to those using screen readers, and they don't show up in question summaries."

Comment: For the first comment: Yes, I wanted to make sure that the conclusion which you called "immediate" is correct. I was worried about the possibility that since the proposition starts with "Let ... be an affine transformation ..." it is applicable to cases where we are given an affine transformation with the definition stated in my question.

Comment: For the second one: Do you suggest writing everything in my scanned paper in the LaTex format, or writing only the key parts (such as the definition of a Euclidean frame) in my proof?

Comment: Use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), which is the simple version of LaTeX for this site.

Comment: "Let $f$ be an affine transformation..." is another way to state the universal quantifier: "For all affine transformations $f$..."

Comment: Also, $E^n$ and $R^n$ are the same thing.

Comment: All the definitions and propositions including my proof are in the mathjax format now.